# how can i get the cpuinfo of remotely connected system in centos?

Tags: linux, ssh, centos

i am a newbie to linux(Centos 6.3) . Please forgive me for this simple question.
in my `localhost` i'll get the cpuinfo by using this `cat /proc/cpuinfo`.
if i want to get the remote system which is connected in my network.

1. Is it possible to get with out ssh ???
2. if not, how can i do that with out password for ssh. I red some posts, generating rsa keys in remote machines and copying to my localhost. With out these, is it possible to get `cpuinfo` and `meminfo` of remotely connected machines.
   Because i want to display the info in Php. That's why i m afraid of ssh. Because if the user change password, again i need to generate keys and copying them to my `.ssh` folder...
   is there any easy way to do that ??

Comment: Your reasoning is incorrect. If you have access by ssh key, changing the password won't do anything to affect you.

Comment: thank you - David Schwartz
Any other ways to find the **cpuinfo** and **meminfo** of remote system in a network -David Schwartz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to use staf for this purpose http://staf.sourceforge.net/,  all you need to do is set trust between machines, nothing to worry about authentication. alternatively you can write a daemon (program) which just push the cpuinfo and meminfo to clients on request.